# How to specify Image type in Google Custom Search

Tags: java, google-custom-search, bing-api

I am using Google Custom Search to get images with some criteria. 
I am initiating HTTP Get requests from java application to call the Google Custom Search API 
 (Please note I am **NOT** using javascript or css and I am **NOT** developing web site).

I am able to get the images, and the program is working. the application brings  images which has `Jpg` extension.

I want to :

- bring **ONLY** the images which has `png` extension **AND** has transparent background.

I tried to specify the `filetype` in the query string of the request URL like this

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=cars&filetype=png&cx=[myinformatino]&searchType=image&rights=cc_publicdomain&num=10&key=[myKey]
```

but the result is really still in `jpg` and the Google Custom search brings only one or two result.

**Notes**

- I configured the Google Custom Search (from its Control panel) to search all the web, I am not restricting it to search some sites.
- I configured the Google Custom Search to enable the Image Searching (also from Control panel) like this

[image]

- I also configured the search result to the ImageResult (from the `Search Features` -> `Advanced` page) as the following picture

[image]

I also founded [this code examples from google documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search#filetype) which restrict the type of the Image but they seems to be in javascripts (NOT in java) which not suitable for me at all.

**UPDATE**
I found a solution for searching for `png` files, the solution was by providing the `filetype:png` in the query itself instead of specify this value as query string to the Google Custom Search. and The result is reasonable and acceptable.

**UPDATE**
I also tried the `tbs` query string parameter which is used in the Google Image search which worked as the following if we want to get the transparent images

```
?tbs=ic:trans&
```

this works only for Google Image Search, But it did not work in the Google Custom Search. Even when I used the `hq` parameter for the Google Custom Search which just add the parameter as it is to the url to add the `tbs` parameter.

BUT I Still can not fore the Google Custom Search to bring the Images which has the transparent background only.

**UPDATE**

if there is a way to achieve the same goal (bringing the images with transparent background) using Bing Search API, I will also accept the answer.
I tried also the Bing Search API, It worked also, but the same problem appeared, there is no way to specify that I need a images with transparent background.

**UPDATE**
according to [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-ajax-search-api/7zM5i_zX7ok)
there is undocumented parameter in the Google deprecated search api which do bring the transparent images, which as the following

```
imgc=trans
```

this is working for the old deprecated google search api, but it does not work for the new API and it does not worked also for the BING api.

**UPDATE**
For Bing Search API I tried to add this query parameter which speicyf the transparent background in the BING image search (in the website not in the API) to the URL

```
qft=+filterui:photo-transparent
```

although this is working for the Normal BING search, it did not work for the BING Search API.

Answer (score 2):

Looking the url of image search, I found that the parameter is tbs. 

For exemple:
transparent image : `...&tbs=ic:trans&....`
gray image: `...&tbs=ic:gray&...`
specific color (Eg: orange): `...&tbs=ic:specific,isc:orange&...`

M.

Comment: I tried this before it works for the google images search. but it did not works for the Google Custom Search, I am sorry because i did not said that before in my question

Comment: I updated my question to include note about this feature. Thanks you any way for your time.

Answer (score 1):

for the Bing question, this feature is not implemented in the API yet.

Comment: do you have reference to for this??

Comment: Well, it's hard to find a reference for something that do not exists ;)
The official documentation does not mention the transparent search request criteria https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=9C9479871FBFA822!109&app=Word&authkey=!ACvyZ_MNtngQyCU

Comment: It is now possible to search for transparent images only https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-image-search/concepts/bing-image-search-get-images#filter-images

Answer (score 1):

How about putting "transparent" at the end of query string? It worked for me: `&q="<brand>+logo+transparent"`
and for filetype `&filetype=png`